# MeteorJS server-render package loads modules only used on client side

Tags: reactjs, meteor, server-side

I have a MeteorJS application with a React front-end. I'm using the server-render atmosphere package to server-side render my react components. After debugging the application using

`meteor --settings private/local-settings.json --exclude-archs web.browser.legacy,web.cordova --inspect-brk=49179`

it appears that the node runtime attempts to load all the installed node modules, including ones that are only imported in client-side code at `.meteor/local/build/programs/server/runtime.js`. Since these modules are being loaded on the server side, and not in a web browser, a rather annoying exception is raised that **window** is not defined, which makes sense since the window object doesn't exist outside the browser. I've looked through the Meteor documentation as well as the server-render package, even stepping through it with a debugger and trying to find out where and why that module is loaded since it's not being used anywhere in server-side code. I uninstalled and re-installed meteor, ran meteor reset to clear my bundle cache, deleted the top level node modules folder as well as any lock files and re-installed those packages. However nothing seems to resolve the error. I am at my wits end. (╯°□°）╯︵ ┻━┻

Node version => v12.16.1

```
=> Started proxy.
W20200809-14:54:22.710(-5)? (STDERR) Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:49179/xxx-xxx
W20200809-14:54:22.741(-5)? (STDERR) For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
W20200809-14:54:22.741(-5)? (STDERR) Debugger attached.
W20200809-16:46:28.008(-5)? (STDERR) Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
W20200809-16:46:28.075(-5)? (STDERR) /Users/tim/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.2.6hsx6.cly95j++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:280
W20200809-16:46:28.076(-5)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20200809-16:46:28.076(-5)? (STDERR)                        ^
W20200809-16:46:28.076(-5)? (STDERR) 
W20200809-16:46:28.076(-5)? (STDERR) ReferenceError: window is not defined
W20200809-16:46:28.077(-5)? (STDERR)     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tim/Timothy/personal_projects/LC/node_modules/lit-html/lib/shady-render.js:35:1)
W20200809-16:46:28.077(-5)? (STDERR)     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
W20200809-16:46:28.077(-5)? (STDERR)     at Module.Mp._compile (/Users/tim/Timothy/personal_projects/LC/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/runtime.js:50:23)
W20200809-16:46:28.077(-5)? (STDERR)     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
W20200809-16:46:28.077(-5)? (STDERR)     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
W20200809-16:46:28.077(-5)? (STDERR)     at Module.Mp.load (/Users/tim/Timothy/personal_projects/LC/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/runtime.js:15:31)
W20200809-16:46:28.078(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
W20200809-16:46:28.078(-5)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
W20200809-16:46:28.078(-5)? (STDERR)     at Module.moduleLink [as link] (/Users/tim/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.10.2.6hsx6.cly95j++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.browser.legacy+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/reify/lib/runtime/index.js:52:22)
W20200809-16:46:28.078(-5)? (STDERR)     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tim/Timothy/personal_projects/LC/node_modules/lit-element/lit-element.js:1:13)
W20200809-16:46:28.078(-5)? (STDERR)     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
W20200809-16:46:28.078(-5)? (STDERR)     at Module.Mp._compile (/Users/tim/Timothy/personal_projects/LC/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/runtime.js:50:23)
W20200809-16:46:28.079(-5)? (STDERR)     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
W20200809-16:46:28.079(-5)? (STDERR)     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
W20200809-16:46:28.079(-5)? (STDERR)     at Module.Mp.load (/Users/tim/Timothy/personal_projects/LC/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/runtime.js:15:31)
W20200809-16:46:28.079(-5)? (STDERR)     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
W20200809-16:46:28.079(-5)? (STDERR)     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1044:19)
W20200809-16:46:28.080(-5)? (STDERR)     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:77:18)
W20200809-16:46:28.080(-5)? (STDERR)     at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/tim/Timothy/personal_projects/LC/node_modules/filestack-adaptive/build/main/index.js:6:21)
W20200809-16:46:28.080(-5)? (STDERR)     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1158:30)
W20200809-16:46:28.080(-5)? (STDERR)     at Module.Mp._compile (/Users/tim/Timothy/personal_projects/LC/.meteor/local/build/programs/server/runtime.js:50:23)
W20200809-16:46:28.080(-5)? (STDERR)     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
=> Exited with code: 1
=> Your application is crashing. Waiting for file change.
```

**LC/server/index.js**

```
onPageLoad(sink => {
    const { host } = sink.request.headers;
    let { pathname } = sink.request.url;

    if (pathname) pathname = pathname.toLowerCase();

    const headerContent = getHeaderContent(host, pathname);

    if (headerContent) {
        headerContent.forEach(header => {
            sink.appendToHead(header);
        });
    }

    const firstPaint = getFirstPaintAssetUrl(pathname);

    try {
        if (firstPaint) {
            const firstPaintAsset = Assets.getText(firstPaint);
            sink.appendToBody(firstPaintAsset);
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
});
```

Comment: `window` doesn't show up in the code you are showing. What's the significance of that code? Can you show the code where the error is thrown? I don't know the server-render package, but to render React server-side you can just use https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom-server.html, which works like a charm.